# Interrogative and exclamation methods

Tags: ruby, methods

When should a method name be interrogative and exclamation? Is there any convention/rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The question mark on a method signifies that the method returns a boolean result.
- The exclamation point at the end of a method signifies the method will modify the object that it is called on.  Ruby calls these “dangerous” methods because they change the state of the object.  A method without an exclamation point is considered a “safe” method because it makes a copy of the object and returns the copy instead of modifying the passed in object.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the bang operator (!) is placed on methods that are destructive i.e. they change things.  `.map` is safe, whilst `.map!` changes the object it is called upon.

Interrogative generally return a boolean response.

Answer (score 1):

Interrogative  - when the method expects boolean values in return.

Exclamation - when the method overwrites the object which is called upon.